# Socket IO error "Access to XMLHttpRequest has been blocked by CORS policy"

Tags: node.js, express, sockets, websocket, socket.io

my app has recently received an error

> "Access to XMLHttpRequest at
>   'https://my-service-domain/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=M-eWtUQ'
>   from origin 'https://my-app-domain' has been blocked by CORS policy:
>   No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
>   resource."

when i connecting to socket.io. I have not yet found a solution to this problem, I will describe in detail as the image below, has anyone ever encountered this error.

[image]

Server config:

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();

app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "X-Requested-With");
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Content-Type");
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "PUT, GET, POST, DELETE, OPTIONS");
  next();
});
var http = require('http');
var server = http.createServer(app);
var io = require('socket.io').listen(server, {log:false, origins:'*:*'});
```

Client config:

```
var socket = io('https://my-service-domain', {transports: ['polling']});
socket.on(channel_id, function(data){
     // some code
});
```

I tried to switch the websocket connection option `var socket = io('https://my-service-domain', {transports: ['websocket']})`, I got the error

> "WebSocket connection to 'wss://my-service-domain/socket.io/?EIO=3&
>   transport = websocket' failed: Error during WebSocket handshake:
>   Unexpected response code: 400 "

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Socket.io + Node.js Cross-Origin Request Blocked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24058157/socket-io-node-js-cross-origin-request-blocked)

Answer (score 22):

```
If you are using Socket.IO v3, you need to explicitly enable Cross-Origin Resource Sharing (CORS).
const io = require("socket.io")(httpServer, {
  cors: {
    origin: "http://localhost:8080",
    methods: ["GET", "POST"]
  }
});

httpServer.listen(3000);
```

Comment: Indeed in works for browsers, but what about mobile apps? Their origin always changes..

Comment: Thanks this saved me from few hours of online research :)

Answer (score 13):

It is 100% working.. I have spend 2 hours in it and at last find the answer .
Just replace code with this...

```
const express = require("express")
var app = express();
var server = app.listen(4000);
var io = require('socket.io')(server, {
    cors: {
      origin: '*',
    }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```js
const io = new Server(httpServer, {
  cors: {
    origin: true,
    credentials: true,
  },
  allowEIO3: true,
});
```

This works for me. I saw this answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68063999/9387851)

Answer (score 1):

For multiple urls:

```
var io = require('socket.io')(server, {
    cors: {
      origin: ['url1','url2',..]
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using HTTPS protocol, then try using the following snippet:

```
var http = require('https');
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are facing the same kind of error where your access to the request has been blocked then change your code from.....
const socket = io('http://localhost:8000');
to this
const socket = io('http://localhost:8000',{transports: ['websocket']});

this will make your code to run

Comment: This does not solve this issue and I don't see why it would

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use `cors` npm package. Install [CORS](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cors) using the following command:

`npm install cors`

Then at the top of your application file, import the installed CORS package as,

`const cors = require('cors');`

then use this constant variable as middleware,

`app.use(cors());`

and it will handle all the CORS related options and settings you need.

**Note:** You should use `app.use(cors());` line before initiating your routers. Otherwise it may not work.

Answer (score 0):

One way i found around this was by using "**prependListener**".
This will only work for socket.io 4.1.0 and above

```
const express = require('express')
const app = express()
const server = require('http').createServer(app);
const io = require('socket.io')(server)
io.on('connection', socket=>{
   // all socket events here
});

// Magic Lines
server.prependListener("request", (req, res) => {
   res.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
});
// instead of "*" your can also add the other domain/servername
server.listen(7000, () => {
   console.log("This is the socket server running");
});
```

Answer (score -1):

When I hosted on Heroku my nodejs app that uses socekt.io I got the same error in my browser. The problem was that I didnot add a start script in package.json file. So heroku could no way start my app. When I added the start script, then the problem was solved.

Comment: What is `start script`?

Comment: @OliverD I think he is referring to package.json scripts, like test and start. If you don't define a start script in your package.json file, it may cause startup failures in various deploment environments.