# Writing to firestore database with 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*'

Tags: angular, google-cloud-firestore, angularfire2

I'm having trouble with saving some data into firestore db. I'm building an investing app for Steam (the gaming platform) items. All I'm using is Angular with Firebase, basically serverless app. But I'm having problems with CORS. Steam API is blocking me, so I found a Chrome extension that puts 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin':'*' into headers. The workaround would be to have a backend and setup proxy I guess, but I don't want to do that.
Now with this header enabled, it also sends the same header when I'm trying to save the data into firestore and gives me this error:

`Access to fetch at 'https://firestore.googleapis.com/google.firestore.v1.Firestore/Write/channel?VER=8&database=projects%2Fmy-project%2Fdatabases%2F(default)&RID=99874&CVER=22&X-HTTP-Session-Id=gsessionid&zx=c3jxa6c9ljcr&t=1' from origin 'https://xyz.web.app' has been blocked by CORS policy: The value of the 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header in the response must not be the wildcard '*' when the request's credentials mode is 'include'.`

The code I'm using in Angular to process getting json data from steam api and saving it into firestore looks like:

```
this.getMarketData(steamCallUrl).subscribe(response => {
      console.log(response.lowest_price)
      let newInvestment = {
        name: formValue.name,
        steamUrl: steamCallUrl,
        buyPrice: +formValue.buyPrice,
        currentPrice: parseFloat(response.lowest_price.replace('€', '').replace(',', '.')),
        quantity: +formValue.quantity,
        investedAt: new Date(formValue.investedAt),
        history: [{date: new Date(), price: parseFloat(response.lowest_price.replace('€', '').replace(',', '.'))}]
      };

      let investments = collection(this.db, 'investments');
      return addDoc(investments, newInvestment);
    });
```

Also in the db itself, I haven't set up any rules, simply `allow read, write: if true;`

Now this app is not gonna be commercial or used by anyone else but me. So if there's a simple but 'not recommended' fix, I'll happily take that.

Comment: Can you check if this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50614397/value-of-the-access-control-allow-origin-header-in-the-response-must-not-be-th) address your concern? You may also check this [blog](https://bobbyhadz.com/blog/the-value-of-the-access-control-allow-origin-header-in-the-response#the-value-of-the-access-control-allow-origin-header-in-the-response-must-not-be-the-wildcard--when-the-requests-credentials-mode-is-include) as well. Hope these help.